# How to incorporate a Javascript function with the cognos Finish button?

Tags: javascript, cognos, cognos-8, cognos-10

I'm working on Cognos 10.1 report studio.  There is a requirement where I should incorporate a  javascript function with the Cognos Prompt button ("Finish").  I've tried all possible ways I know but I couldn't achieve it.  Please help me.

I should either be able to incorporate the Javascript function with the Cognos prompt button or get the functionality of a Cognos prompt button in a Javascript button.  Any one of these would fulfill my requirement.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is an official IBM document regarding this [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21343513).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in javascript;

```
 promptButtonFinish();
```